# Get the earliest date with maximum occurrences from a list

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list which contains dates and the same date can be repeated multiple times.

```
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();

foreach (List<string> l in reservations)
{
    var start = Convert.ToDateTime(l.First());
    var end   = Convert.ToDateTime(l.Last());

    for (var date = start.Date; date.Date <= end.Date; date = date.AddDays(1))
        dates.Add(date);
}
```

I want to find the date with maximum occurrences. If there are multiple dates with the maximum occurrence, I need to get the earliest date. Here's the LINQ query I wrote:

```
DateTime max = dates.GroupBy(s => s)
                        .OrderByDescending(s => s.Count())
                        .ThenBy(s => s)
                        .First().Key;
```

Here I'm getting the error:

> At least one object must implement IComparable.'

How do I do this?

Comment: Could your show `dates` collections code?

Answer (score 2):

@Servy is correct.

I would suggest:

```
DateTime max = dates.GroupBy(s => s)
                    .OrderByDescending(sg => sg.Count())
                    .ThenBy(sg => sg.Key)
                    .First().Key;
```

Comment: Came up with the same solution. Works!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to order by a *group* of dates.  An entire group of dates can't be compared to another group of dates (unless you supply a custom comparer).

You probably want to order on the group's key, which is a single date, not on the entire group.